# full calendar not showing in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, fullcalendar

I am making an agenda in fullcalendar. It works fine in all browsers except for IE. It renders the entries I can see that in the source-code, but it is not showing them in the browser. I have made my website in Expression Engine. The code which I use is:

```
<link href='{site_url}ontwerp/intranet/scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='{site_url}ontwerp/intranet/scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='{site_url}ontwerp/intranet/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<script src='{site_url}ontwerp/intranet/scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js'>  </script>
<script src='{site_url}ontwerp/intranet/scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<script>


$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: [
            {embed="intern/agenda_data"}
        ]
    });

});

</script>
```

The embed/agenda_data:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="agenda" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="yes" dynamic="off" limit="99999"}
{
    title: '{title}',
    start  : '{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"}',
    end : '{expiration_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"}',

    {if agenda_categorie=="Vakantie"}color: '#f5a320'{/if}
    {if agenda_categorie=="Events VB"}color: '#c03d09'{/if}
    {if agenda_categorie=="Betaalperiode"}color: '#5f781c'{/if}
    {if agenda_categorie=="Decoratie"}color: '#186490'{/if}
},
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It would be great if there is someone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of IE, it won't support the open comma at the end of that JS object. If you do `backspace=1` in your channel entry loop, it should fix the issue.